# Switch between animated elements of svg with Angular 4

Tags: angular, animation, svg

I want to animate an svg in an Angular 4 component. How do I grab different ids within the svg component and animate them sequentially?

I can trigger a single animation on a single element of my svg by a click event, but how do I trigger this on page load?

I have the following component.ts code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate, keyframes } from '@angular/animations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-splash',
  templateUrl: './splash.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./splash.component.css'],

  animations: [
    trigger('myAwesomeAnimation', [

      state('offscreen', style({
        transform: 'translateY(-50px)',
      })),

      state('onscreen', style({
        transform: 'translateY(50px)',
      })),

      transition('offscreen => onscreen', animate('500ms 500ms ease-in')),

    ]),
  ]

})

export class SplashComponent implements OnInit {

  state: string = 'offscreen';

  animateMe() {
    this.state = (this.state === 'offscreen' ? 'onscreen' : 'offscreen');
  }

  constructor(private dataService:DataService) {

  }

  someProperty:string = '';

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.dataService.cars);
    this.someProperty = this.dataService.myData();
  }
}
```

My html part of the component is more complicated because of the complexity of my svg, but I just have one animated element so far:

```
<g id="IsEverything" [@myAwesomeAnimation]='state'(click)="animateMe()"> ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Josh Morony did a Youtube video of something similiar with Ionic [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XN8nzM3Kbko). Ionic uses Angular under the covers too. It does use Sass in his video.

Within the svg element of his example he gave classes to each sub-element like circle, rect, polygon and and attached CSS animation to the classes and @keyframes. Hope that helps..

Comment: @Davtho1983 Have you seen this article? https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/07/26/a-web-animations-deep-dive-with-angular.html

Comment: I hadn't thanks! I saw some of his others - I don't know why that particular one eluded me - looks like it will help tho!